# В чем ошибка обьявления функции в паскале?

Tags: pascal

```
const
m=10;
n=2;
k=3;
type
an=array[1..m,1..n,1..k]of integer;
var
a:an;
x,y,z,p:integer;

function s(a:an; var mm,nn,kk:integer):integer;  {Вот ТУТ не нравится 8_20.pas(11,10) Warning: Function result does not seem to be set}

begin
writeln('m=',mm+1);
end;

begin
p:=0;
for x:=1 to m do
    for y:=1  to n do
        for z:=1 to k do begin
            p:=p+1;
            a[x,y,z]:=p+1;
            end;        
            for x:=1 to m do begin
    for y:=1  to n do begin
        for z:=1 to k do
        write(a[x,y,z]:3);
    writeln;
        end;
        writeln;
        end;
        s(a,m,n,k);{Вот ТУТ не нравится 8_20.pas(34,3) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "s"}
end.
```

{Вот ТУТ не нравится 8_20.pas(36) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping}

Comment: Ну так написано же -- результат не устанавливается. Вероятно, Вам нужна не функция, а процедура. Тут Вам не Це

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция ничего не возвращает. Используйте procedure.

Синтаксис функции:

> ```
> function имя функции (формальные параметры):тип результата;  
>    раздел описаний функции  
> begin  
>   исполняемая часть функции
>
>   имя функции := возвращаемое значение;
> ```
>
> end;

Вызов функции:

> переменная := имя функции
> (формальные параметры);

Comment: @samoilow
необходимо использовать функцию